# Use an element twice in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML data file that contains the data already grouped and ordered. I just need to bring it in and massage it a bit.

So, I created the XSLT to bring in the content in the order I need it, but I'd like to use a data element twice, but xsl:copy-of doesn't work. It's probably something really simple but I can't figure it out.

Here is a simplified version of the XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
    <xsl:output method="xml" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <dataroot>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="dataroot" />
        </dataroot>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="CaseStudies">
        <xsl:text></xsl:text>
        <CaseStudies>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="H1" />
            <xsl:text></xsl:text>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="code" />
            <xsl:apply-templates select="tip" />
        </CaseStudies>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="code">
        <code>
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </code>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="tip[string-length() != 0]">
        <xsl:text></xsl:text>
        <Head>Coding Tip for <xsl:copy-of select="code" /></Head>
        <xsl:text></xsl:text>
        <tip>
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </tip>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here is some sample XML:

```
<dataroot>
    <CaseStudies>
        <H1>Heading</H1>
        <code>90034</code>
        <tip>Here is the tip text</tip>
    </CaseStudies>
    <CaseStudies>
        <H1>Heading</H1>
        <code>90501</code>
        <tip>Here is the tip text</tip>
    </CaseStudies>
    <CaseStudies>
        <H1>Heading</H1>
        <code>90601</code>
        <tip>Here is the tip text</tip>
    </CaseStudies>
</dataroot>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are matching `tip[string-length() != 0]`, the context in this template is "tip" node.
using `code` xpath implies it's a child of `tip` element which is not the case in your input xml.

use xpath to select `code` from parent of `tip` node:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="../code"/>
```

Or to copy only the text:

```
<xsl:value-of select="../code"/>
```

Comment: That was it. I should have seen that. Thanks